# Exception on dealloc of an object was observed using Key Value Observing

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, key-value-observing

One of my iOS projects uses a custom collection class which observes the stored objects using `KVO`:

```
@interface EntityCollection () {
    NSMutableArray *entities;
}

@implementation EntityCollection

- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init])
        entities = [NSMutableArray array];
    return self;
}

- (void)addEntity:(Entity *)entity {
    [entities addObject:entities];
    [entity addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"someKey" options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld | NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew) context:nil];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    for (Entity *entity in entities)
        [entity removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"someKey"];
}

...
```

So, the `Key Value Observing` is added when the `Entity` object is added to the collection and removed before the collection is deallocated.

In rare cases an `NSInternalInconsistencyException` is thrown, then collection object is deallocated:

```
EntityCollection *entities = [[EntityCollection alloc] init];
[entities addEntity:someEntity];
...

// dealloc / release the collection by simply creating a new instance
entities = [[EntityCollection alloc] init];  // ==> crash
```

Once the `EntityCollection` is re-created the ARC jumps in and releases the object, which leads to an exception:

```
MyApp[5861:9918336] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', 
reason: 'An instance 0x6180008f0780 of class Entity was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it. 
Current observation info: <NSKeyValueObservationInfo 0x610002438b20> ( <NSKeyValueObservance 0x610002642b50: Observer: 0x6100026428e0, Key path: someKey, Options: <New: YES, Old: YES, Prior: NO Context: 0x0, Property: 0x618000442100>
)'

*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation               0x000000011471ab0b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib              0x0000000114186141 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation               0x0000000114783625 +[NSException raise:format:] + 197
    3   Foundation                   0x00000001113209d3 NSKVODeallocate + 294
    4   libobjc.A.dylib              0x000000011419ab8e _ZN11objc_object17sidetable_releaseEb + 202
    5   CoreFoundation               0x00000001147712ad common_removeAllObjects + 189
    6   CoreFoundation               0x00000001146523d3 -[__NSArrayM dealloc] + 19
    7   libobjc.A.dylib              0x000000011419ab8e _ZN11objc_object17sidetable_releaseEb + 202
    8   MyApp                        0x000000010f64caa0 -[EntityCollection .cxx_destruct] + 208
    9   libobjc.A.dylib              0x00000001141849bc _ZL27object_cxxDestructFromClassP11objc_objectP10objc_class + 127
    10  libobjc.A.dylib              0x0000000114190d34 objc_destructInstance + 129
    11  CoreFoundation               0x000000011478a2e6 -[NSObject(NSObject) __dealloc_zombie] + 150
    12  MyApp                        0x000000010f644986 -[EntityCollection dealloc] + 630
....
```

I cannot reproduce the issue and it occurs only in very rare cases. It seem to be a race condition on whether the `KVO` is removed before the observed object is released.

However I do not understand how this is possible:

- The variable that points to the `EntityCollection` instance is assigned to a new `EntityCollection` instance
- ARC recognizes, that no variable is assigned to the first `EntityCollection` instance and thus releases it
- Before the instance is released, the `dealloc` method is called. Within this method the `KVO` is removed from all `Entity` objects that are stored in the internal `entities` array.
- Since the internal `entities` array holds a reference to each contained `Entity` object, these objects should not be released before the `dealloc` is complete an the `EntityCollection` itself is released.

So, how is it possible that some (at least one) of the contained `Entity` objects is released, before the `EntityCollection` had a chance to remove its `KVO`?

Comment: Wouldnt it be better to subclass the entity and implement dealloc on the object rather than the collection telling it to remove its own observers, I find this way best for things like AVPlayerItem's when you nearly always want to observer details.

Comment: The collection is responsible for starting the observation. Should't it be responsible for ending it as well? Does an object even know, that it is observed and can end the observation?